# Jquery Toggle & Offclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to jquery so I wondered if someone could help me.

I've made a toggle function. When you click on the user_button the user_info shows, when you offclick the user_info disapears. But now I want to let the user_info disapear also when you click again on user_info (so when it is open it closes).

This is the jquery I have. Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#user_button").click(function(){
    $("#user_button").addClass("active")
    $("#user_box").toggle();
});
$("#user_box").mouseup(function(){
    return false;
});
$(this).mouseup(function() {
    $("#user_button").removeClass("active");
    $("#user_box").hide();
});
});
```

Comment: please provide your HTML also..

Comment: Your code is proper,what is your problem?

Comment: provide your jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry! http://jsfiddle.net/3Nxz2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a testable example on for example jsfiddle.net? This allows other to "play" with the actual code.

Try to take look at methods suchas show, hide, toggle toggleClass etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take your code =>   http://jsfiddle.net/3Nxz2/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#user_button").click(function(){
        //alert("click");
        $("#user_button").addClass("active")
        $("#user_box").toggle();
    });
    $("#user_box").mouseup(function(){
        //return false;
    });
    $(this).mouseup(function() {
        $("#user_button").removeClass("active");
        //$("#user_box").hide();
    });
});
```